# Baofeng's won't talk to each other - but other radios receive the signal

Tags: baofeng

I'm very new to this radio stuff and I've come across a problem.

I have two BF-888S', along with two other radios. (Binatone Terrain 750)
All of which are on the same frequency and have the same settings. The problem is that whenever I transmit with of the Baofengs, the other doesn't receive it - but the other two radios do.
If I transmit on the Binatones, the other three radios receive the signal. If I transmit on one of the Baofengs, the Binatones receive it but not the other Baofeng.

Like I said, all are on the same frequency. I'm using PMR446 range, if that's relevant.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Frequencies]
[image: Settings]

Comment: Hi James, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I just did [this search](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is%3Aquestion+Baofeng+problem+-charger+-antenna). It looks like there are a few similar questions and answers that may help.

Comment: I believe I have the same problem. Bought two BF888s radios, saved the original configuration with Chirp. Programmed it with the PMR 446 frequencies but the radios do not communicate with each other. Tried several programs and (tons of) configurations, I get quite often the squelch problem. One thing I noticed is that the green light is not lit after writing the PMR446 frequencies to the radio.

Comment: I kept trying all the configs and I just realized that I have success for a brief moment if I 1. Connect the radio to the cable and turn it on 2. Write the original factory frequencies with Chirp 3. Write the PMR446 frequencies with 888s v1.05 4. Unplug the radio WITHOUT turning it off. The green light will be on, there is no squelch problem and the radios seem to receive each other communication. As soon as I change channel or turn the radio off and on the radios won't communicate with each other anymore and the green light won't be lit. I was able to replicate this behaviour a couple times.

Comment: update to the test mentioned above. It seems to be replicable when the radio channel is set to 1 or 10. On channel 2 and 3 seems to result in the squelch issue

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have the CTCSS or DCS settings wrong on the Baofengs.  Assuming you're trying to talk simplex and not through a repeater, turn all those settings off, and all three radios should be able to talk to each other.

I suspect the real problem is unfamiliarity with the software.  I get tripped up using manufacturers' programming software.  If you're using the Baofeng software, try using [CHIRP](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home) instead; it's better-written, better-documented, and easier to use.

You might consider editing your question to include a screenshot of the software if you're still stuck.

Comment: I've messed around with Chirp, and now I can receive signals ONLY if I am holding down the monitor button. I'm guessing it's something to do with the squelch, but I've tried changing it to each value from 9 to 0.

Comment: Something I should add is that the squelch seems to high when it is on NFM (narrow), as in, on the lowest setting, it doesn't pick up anything, but when on the wide option it seems to weak, even on the highest, and picks up everything/interference/static.

Comment: The monitor button bypasses the squelch, but it also bypasses CTCSS and DCS.  I know the squelch function isn't great on my UV-5R+, but the squelch on any radio shouldn't block the radio from receiving a transmission from another HT in the same room.  I don't think the squelch is the problem if the radios work fine with the bogus frequencies and settings programmed into the channels by the manufacturer.  I recommend you edit your question to insert a screenshot of your CHIRP settings.

Comment: Added two screenshots; frequencies & settings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshots.  I presume that you tried on both FM and NFM.  You clearly have CTCSS and DCS off.  I'm stumped now too!

Comment: Yeah, tried both. I've just discovered that on Channel 2 (config hasn't changed since screenie) I can transmit and receive, however I pick up static/interference when I'm not transmitting. It's like the squelch is too low and is picking up everything, but only on that channel. I'll have a little play with the antennas and physical side of things to see if that makes a difference. Thanks for your continued help

Comment: I've come around to thinking that you could be right, your problem could very well be defects in the squelch circuit.  BTW your radios could be picking up an external signal on channel 2, or even an internal "birdie", that is keeping the squelch open.

Comment: My UV-5R+ has a channel or two where the squelch is always open; I had to program the scan function to skip those channels.  Also sometimes I'll be in town in the drive-through at the bank or something and suddenly scan will stop on another channel that is just unmodulated carrier plus static; when I drive away from the bank, the interference goes away and the radio starts scanning again.  I don't think the bank is transmitting a carrier on the ham band, I think the radio is poorly shielded and is picking up a strong off-band signal that generates intermod on the ham band.

Comment: I'm being chatty now, and I should mention that we have a great [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11162/ham-shack) where there are no rules about staying on topic.  Unfortunately you need 50 reputation points to go there, but stick around and contribute a little and you'll soon have those points.

Comment: So I was going to say that I got tired of my ancient HT with the huge clunky NiMH battery and the charger that will fry the battery if I don't disconnect it at the right time.  And I got tired of the birdies and the messy signal of my UV-5R+, so I finally sprung for a modern better-quality HT from a Japanese manufacturer.  It cost four times what a Baofeng costs, but everything works better and I'm very happy with it.